# How to make it mandatory to select a value in Autoselect while using template

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui

Scenario : we have a Kendo UI template. When a user tries to type atleast 2 charters data is populated in Autocomplete widget. I cannot use combobox as return data may be huge and combobox freezes. I want to force user to select a option from Auto complete dropdown and if nothing is returned from autocomplete or if user not select a data I want to clear the text field.The issue with my code is that everytime it clears the first row in the template and not the relevant one where data is not selected.
Template declaration

```
<script id="newTestTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div id="testRec">
   <input id="pSearchId"  class="pSearch"
           data-role="autocomplete"
           data-placeholder="Select from dropdown"
           data-text-field="name"
           type="text"
           data-bind="source: pSearchDS, value: name, events: {select: pSelected,open : pOpen,close : pClose}"
           data-min-length="2"
           data-highlight-first="true" maxlength="160" />
    <input id="pDesc" data-role="textbox" placeholder="Description" class="k-textbox part-input" data-bind="value: description/> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   pOpen = function (e) {
        valid = false;
    }

    pClose = function (e) {
        if (!valid) {
           $(e.sender).closest(".pSearch").val("");
           $("#pDesc").val('');   //tried this way too
        }
    } 
     pSelected = function (e) {
        valid = true;
    }
```

Please suggest . If there is anyother way to force implement selection then let me know that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following on Autocomplete blur check if the user selected any value if not clear the values

```
$("#pSearchId").blur(function(){
      if (!valid) {
        alert("User not selected any value");
           $("#pSearchId").val('');
           $("#pDesc").val('');
        }

    });
```

Comment: This is not working . the code doesn't seems to be called.

Answer (score 0):

For this I ended up putting validation on the click even to check if text box have a value.